# Shield MFC image resource for CMFCButton

Tags: button, mfc, icons

Here is a button with an image captured from Inno Script Studio:

[image: Inno Script Studio]

I have added a button to my own MFC application (of type `CMFCButton`):

[image: My Button]

I have been trying to find if there is a built-in **shield** image in the MFC resources or must I find my own?

Comment: I would have loved to have offered an answer myself (especially the `IDI_SHIELD` thing) ... however, I can't really improve on the answers given in the dupe, and we really should avoid answering known dupes.

Comment: @AdrianMole I ended up using `Button_SetElevationRequiredState(m_btnSetFileAssociations2.GetSafeHwnd(), TRUE);` which does the trick. But I had to use a normal button instead of a `CMFCButton`. Me happy. Thank you.